# javascript oninput: press onekey multiple event fired

Tags: javascript

i'm just starting a typing text project not for english typing text. it's only for Bengali language. my typing project is 99% done for english language but in Bengali language i found a tiny but a big problem.

i have a input box that will match all the word one by one. you type a word and **press space** it will check the word for matching and after that move for the next word. it's work fine.

how i check that:in **inputbox** **oninput** event **event.data === " "** than move to the next word.

but in Bengali language when i press the key "c" (*not as first character but in the middle of word first character*) its fired the oninput event multiple time. with various event.data value include the space also. that's why when **press c in keyboard** its just go to the next word.

now you cannot find out the multiple event in the console because you don't have the software in your machine. so for that i include a screen short of this:
[see_the_picture_for_butter_understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tge7a.jpg)

**onkeyup event problem:** [see_the_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhpQl.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SutonnyMj';
    src: url('assets/fonts/SutonnyMj.ttf'),
    url('assets/fonts/sutonnymj.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('assets/fonts/sutonnymj.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
#textbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-family: 'SutonnyMj';
    font-size: 50px;
}
</style>


<body>
    <textarea id="textbox" type="text"></textarea>
    <script>
        var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
            textBox.oninput = function(e) {
            console.log(event); // multiple event fire when the Software is Enable
            if(event.data === " ") {
                // move_to_the_next_word();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notes:** It's happen because i use a software called ***Bijoy Bangla*** for writing Bengali. (It's require for Bengali Typing Test)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. Please note that `oninput` event is fired after each and every change that occurs in the textarea. So it is normal to execute when you type any character. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ahmad 'input' event is fired after each change, but you can be more specific using 'keyup' event which will provide you more control and attributes for `event` object. For example you will be able to handle 'Space' using `event.which` statement. Here an example:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
            textBox.onkeyup = function(e) {
            console.log(event); 
            if(event.which === 32) { //space keycode
                // move_to_the_next_word();
            }
        }
```

Comment: cannot use keyup event. but i use this for testing purpose it also return event.which === 32 when i press c in the keyboard because its returning the space which has value of **event.which = 32**.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood which key you pressed for the same keycode? Also you are restricted to use only `oninput` event? Why?

Comment: now you will understand what i trying to said see the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhpQl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
function runScript(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 67) {//c
    console.log("you have entred 'c' char")
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 32){//space
    console.log("space ")
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="scriptBox" type="text" onkeyup="return runScript(event)" />
```